# Angular.js ng-repeat filter without knowing key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am having troubles filtering my JSON file in the ng-repeat.

Here is the JSON data which is in my code is coming from Firebase

```
{
"850": {
    "buttonText": "Button TST",
    "description": "",
    "documentNumber": "850",
    "language": "fi",
    "special": false,
    "newOrder": 99000500850
},
"851": {
    "buttonText": "eng ButtonTXT",
    "description": "I would like to get this",
    "documentNumber": "851",
    "language": "en",
    "special": false,
    "newOrder": 99000500851
},
"852": {
    "buttonText": "MORE FInnish button text",
    "description": "Oh my",
    "documentNumber": "852",
    "language": "fi",
    "special": false,
    "newOrder": 99000500015
       }
}
```

The JSON-data is stored into $ctrl.documentMatrixFirebase. Here is the Angular.js HTML. It is component which does what I want to except the filtering part.

```
  <google-docs-card
  layout="column"
  ng-repeat="docButton in $ctrl.documentMatrixFirebase |  
  orderObjectBy:'newOrder' track by docButton.newOrder "
  document-data="docButton"
  subject="$ctrl.subject"
  id="docnum_{{docButton.documentNumber}}"></google-docs-card>
```

Here is the code I tried to use for filtering without luck.

```
<google-docs-card
  layout="column"
  ng-repeat="docButton in $ctrl.documentMatrixFirebase | 
  filter:docButton.language:'en' | 
  orderObjectBy:'newOrder' track by docButton.newOrder "
  document-data="docButton"
  subject="$ctrl.subject"
  id="docnum_{{docButton.documentNumber}}"></google-docs-card>
```

If possible, I would like to avoid adding custom filters for such a simple job.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that AngularJs to Array filter solved the problem:
https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter

I installed the array filter according the instructions and used it in the HTML like this.

```
<google-docs-card
  layout="column"
  ng-repeat="docButton in $ctrl.documentMatrixFirebase 
  |  toArray:false |  filter: {language: 'en'} 
  | orderObjectBy:'newOrder' track by docButton.newOrder"
  document-data="docButton"
  subject="$ctrl.subject"
  id="docnum_{{docButton.documentNumber}}"></google-docs-card>
```